# Serialization of Frequently Changing List

Tags: java, serialization

I have a server application and a client application, and a `List` (an `ArrayList` to be specific) exists at the server. The client sends the server some information, the server modifies parts of the `List`, and sends it to the client by serializing it over the network.

The first time this is done, the client receives the `List` (or is it a copy of/reference to the original?), but after that, the client's `List` never changes though the server sends a modified version. The server is surely modifying the `List` because watching it in a debugger clearly shows the modifications.

The client-side code is like

```
List<Type> fromServer = new ArrayList<>();
...
// send information
...
fromServer = (List<Type>) in.readObject();
```

and the server-side like

```
List<Type> toClient = new ArrayList<>();
...
// get information from client
// add/modify list elements
...
out.writeObject(toClient);
```

where `in` and `out` are input/output streams over sockets.

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this problem? Is it occuring because the `List` is assumed to be unchanged? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: What exactly are you watching in your debugger? Each time the client calls the server it will receive back a brand new List which it stores in the `fromServer` variable, discarding the reference to the previous list - no individual list gets modified at any point. So if you've stored a reference to the original List and you inspect that again after the call then you won't see it changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ObjectOutputStream.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) whenever you need to serialize a new version of the same object.

Comment: OK, this works, but what is the actual problem? Shouldn't a modified object be detected?

Comment: See the linked Javadoc. Serialization doesn't reserialize objects it has already serialized unless you use `reset()` or `writeUnshared().`

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you stop using the built in object serialization.   It has severe drawbacks:

- It uses a binary format that is difficult to debug
- It is version dependent:  both your client and server will need to be running the same version of Java
- Changes to your data structures will likely lead to incompatibilities between your client and server

Instead, I recommend using JSON serialization using a library like [Google Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) or [json-io](https://code.google.com/p/json-io/).   It is much easier to expect the data on the wire (or in the debugger) and make sure that that data you are receiving is what you expect.   It will also allow you to be forward and backward compatible, both with different versions of Java and your own data structures.

Comment: Point (2) is incorrect. Point (3) is neither 'likely' nor 'unlikely': it depends entirely on *what the changes are.*